# synchronise directory with root directory (provisioning)

Tags: linux, bash, provisioning

My google-fu seems to have failed me.

I have a directory structure as follow

```
provisioner/
├── etc
│  ├── apt
│  │  ├── preferences.d
│  │  │  ├── experimental.pref
│  │  │  ├── security.pref
│  │  │  ├── stable.pref
│  │  │  ├── testing.pref
│  │  │  └── unstable.pref
│  │  └── sources.list.d
│  │      ├── experimental.list
│  │      ├── security.list
│  │      ├── stable.list
│  │      ├── testing.list
│  │      └── unstable.list
```

I have full access to the machine, is there a command that would allow me to put everything in provisioner/etc into /etc, provisioner/var inside /var and so on?

Side question: how do you call this?

Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my google-fu isn't really on point.

`rsync` can be used locally:

```
rsync -a provisioner /
```

Comment: I think you want `rsync -a provisioner/  /` to copy *the contents of* the source directory, otherwise you're creating `/provisioner`.  Consider also `-u` to speed things up if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your provisioner directory, loop through them and copy their content to the corresponding directories in the root directory.

```
for d in */; do cp -r "${d}"* /"${d}" ; done
```

Comment: posted my own answer below, found out rsync could be used locally